# How to get user location on google map with source, destination, start time, and (start time + hours) as input to Google Maps API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Android Google Map, with input parameters of source, and destination, and start time, how to know where the user would be after four hours in his traveling path.
Example :  If I start at 6 A.M, i need location details where i would be at 10 A.M in the traveling route before i start my journey.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) which clearly mention :

> The location data available to an Android device includes the current
>   location of the device — pinpointed using a combination of
>   technologies — the direction and method of movement, and whether the
>   device has moved across a predefined geographical boundary, or
>   geofence. Depending upon the needs of your application, you can choose
>   between several ways of working with location data:
>
> - The My Location layer provides a simple way to display a device's    location on the map. It does not provide data.
> - The Google Play services Location API is recommended for all    programmatic requests for location data.
> - The LocationSource interface allows you to provide a custom location    provider.

The implementation of these concepts of MAPS API can be found [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos)

Comment: Hi Lucas, Thanks for your reply. Following is my scenario.  Example : If I start at 6 A.M, i need location details where i would be at 10 A.M in the traveling route before i start my journey. I want to find , Is there any process available.

Comment: Check this for that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/  So this will basically help you predict travel times